# iOS Energy Profiler: What does GPS On/Off Log State actually measure?

Tags: ios, swift, gps, cllocationmanager, cllocation

What does this setting measure?  Is it whether the phone GPS is enabled? Or whether the GPS chip itself is actually on?

I'm using CLLocationManager with background modes to try to efficiently monitor the phone's location.  I thought that if I called stopUpdatingLocation() then the GPS would turn off, but that does not seem to happen.

I even went in and disabled Location Services via Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services but the profiler still says the GPS is on.

How do I get the GPS to turn off?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this happen, i think it may be a bug with the profiler, sometimes it takes a while before it shows GPS as disabled even if you turn it completely off in Privacy

Comment: Oh interesting.  Any tips to get it to work?  I tried restarting my computer etc.  Or, are there any other profiling tools I can use to actually monitor whether the GPS chip itself is on?

Comment: What OS are you running Sierra? Because i know that in Sierra they changed the "console" application that actually shows you each time the app makes a call to get a location update. You may want to give this a shot.